# Have JVM only run .jar files from trusted certifications?

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, truststore

I need to figure out how I can tell the Java Virtual Machine to only run .jar files that is signed with a trusted certification.

Imaging:

- Company have a department with inhouse developers.
- The developer department only creates applications and scripts for the other departments at the location.
- Company uses AppLocker to ensure no unsigned .exe/.ps1/.bat can be run without being signed from a trusted certification.
  I know that AppLocker cannot lockdown .jar files and they are handle by the Java Virtual Machine.

I already created a test enviroment with a Domain Controller (Where AppLocker is located) And a client PC, I tested that the JVM cannot run unsigned files (Which works), however I can create a KeyStore and self-sign a certification which allows it to run (Not what I want)
I read about KeyStore and TrustStore, but do not see any resources on how to implement them in a server enviroment?

My question is: is it possible to create a "global" keystore/truststore where the JRE checks for trusted certificates before running .jar files?

A point in the right direction would be a real help.